# Looping through Inactive worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

Loop code doesnt not on all worksheets at once unless i go to each tab and run it

```
Dim Sheets As Variant
Dim Sheet As Variant

Sheets = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")

For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

If Range("G2").Value = 1 Then Range("h10:h11").Value = 
Range("N10:N11").Value
If Range("G2").Value = 1 Then Range("h14:h22").Value = 
Range("N14:N22").Value
If Range("G2").Value = 1 Then Range("h27:h29").Value = 
Range("N27:N29").Value
Next Sheet
```

how can i fix my code so when im on tab 1 it changes all of the other tabs

Comment: What is happening now?  This should work?  You don't need 3 if's as they all do the same, just put the `Range("h27:h29").Value = ....` etc in a block.  Why define Array of Sheets, and not use it?  Also, stay away from keywords in variable declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do not specify the Parent Sheet in the code you will only get the active sheet.  Use a With Block:

```
Dim Shts As variant
Dim Sheet As Worksheet

Shts = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")

For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets
    With Sheet
        If .Range("G2").Value = 1 Then 
            .Range("h10:h11").Value = .Range("N10:N11").Value
            .Range("h14:h22").Value = .Range("N14:N22").Value
            .Range("h27:h29").Value = .Range("N27:N29").Value
        End If
    End With
Next Sheet
```

Comment: This code will fail if there is any chart-sheet in the workbook. Better to declare Sheet as type Worksheet and use ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets to loop through.

Comment: Also, the Sheets variable is not used.

Comment: @jkpieterse You are correct.  On the array I left it, as it may be used in other code later on.

Comment: Hi this is working now thanks but how can i adjust the code so theres multiple IF statements..

Comment: @ScottCraner can you please see my edit at the very top so you see what im talking about. thank you

Comment: @jonathanmarin please do not change the question, you can append edits, after getting answers.  That totally changes the question and will open me up for down votes by people who did not see the original.  Please roll back the edits and add to it.  Also technically my initial answer is correct and what you are asking is a new question.  Roll back and ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: @jonathanmarin no do not do that I will roll it back

Comment: Thanks for being helpful let me know what else I can do to get my question answered and you receive no thumbs up

Comment: @jonathanmarin btw, what you are missing is the `End If` for each if.

Comment: Thanks, when doing that i now get the error "Cannot enter a null value as an item or field name in a pivot table report"

Comment: That is a new question, please post a new question with the code . @jonathanmarin

Answer (score 0):

Something like so, also checks sheet exists and gives the option to skip the activesheet

```
Sub n()

Dim Shts() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim s As Variant

Shts = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")

For Each s In Shts

    If WORKSHEET_EXISTS(CStr(s)) Then

        '   Exclude the activesheet?
        If s <> ActiveSheet.Name Then

            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(s)
            With ws
                If .Range("G2").Value = 1 Then
                    .Range("h10:h11").Value = .Range("N10:N11").Value
                    .Range("h14:h22").Value = .Range("N14:N22").Value
                    .Range("h27:h29").Value = .Range("N27:N29").Value
                End If
            End With

        '   End of exclude
        End If

    Else

        Debug.Print "Can't find worksheet : " & s

    End If

Next s

Erase Shts

End Sub

Function WORKSHEET_EXISTS(strWorksheetname As String) As Boolean

Dim w As Excel.Worksheet

WORKSHEET_EXISTS = False

On Error GoTo eHandle

Set w = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strWorksheetname)

WORKSHEET_EXISTS = True

ExitFunction:

Exit Function

eHandle:

End Function
```